# web2py representation 'format' in grandchild

Tags: format, data-access-layer, web2py

The [q&a here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746008/1480618) (and the doc) describe the use of the `format=` argument to the define_table function. I have a problem getting that to work in a slightly more complicated case. I'm using web2py version `(1, 99, 7, datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4, 22, 12, 8), 'stable')`, and Python `2.5.4`. (I'm using MySQL, but I assume that's irrelevant.)

I have the following:

'Independent' (not a child) tables `Institution` and `Person`. Table `Team` is a child of `Institution`. Table `Team_staff` connects `Person` and `Team` together. Here's a trimmed version:

```
db.define_table('Person',
                Field('First_name', 'string', length=60, required=True),
                Field('Last_name', 'string', length=60, required=True),
                ...
                format='%(First_name)s %(Last_name)s')

db.define_table('Institution',
                Field('Institution_name', 'string', length=60, required=True,
                   unique=True),
                format='%(Institution_name)s')

db.define_table('Team',
                Field('Institution', db.Institution),
                Field('Sex', 'string', required=True,
                   requires=IS_IN_SET(['m', 'f'])),
                Field('Level', 'string', required=True),
                ...
                format='%(Institution)s %(Sex)s')

db.define_table('Team_staff',
                Field('Team', db.Team),
                Field('Team_staff_member', db.Person),
                ...
                Field('Team_position', 'string', required=True))
```

So far, so good. I have a controller that creates a `SQLFORM(db.Team_staff)`, and a view that simply displays the form. When I drop down the 'Team' dropdown, I see the Institution *id* concatenated with the 'sex' value (such as `1 f`, then `1 m` below that, then `2 f`, and so forth). As `Institution` has `format='%(Institution_name)s'`, why am I not seeing the institution name instead of the institution id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "format" attribute does not propagate across tables that way. Instead, you should be able to define the "format" attribute as a lambda function, which takes a row of the table as its argument:

```
db.define_table('Team', ...,
    format=lambda r: '%s %s' % (db.Institution[r.Institution].Institution_name,
                                r.Sex))
```