# How to show entries from a referenced table in a dropdown and store the ID of the chosen entry

Tags: database, forms, web2py

With two tables:

```
db.define_table('content',
    # Here I want to store the id of the chosen layout_type
    Field('layout_type_id', db.layout_type),
    # Here the plain name - might not be necessary
    Field('layout_type_name', 'list:string')
    )

db.define_table('layout_type',
    Field('layout_type_name', 'string')
    )

db.content.layout_type_name.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'layout_type.id', '%(layout_type_name)s')
```

I create a form

```
form = crud.update(db.mytable, id)
```

where I want a Dropdown menu to choose a `layout_type_name` from - which is working - and store the `id` of the chosen entry.

**How is it possible to store the `id` of the chosen `layout_type_name` in `content.layout_type_id`?**

Also, if I choose one entry in the dropdown mentioned above - the (text)value is not stored when the form is successfully submitted.

Comment: This is not how reference fields work. A reference field stores the record ID of the referenced record -- it does not store values of other fields from the referenced record -- that defeats the purpose of the foreign key, as you are denormalizing the data. Please explain what you are trying to achieve. In particular, do you need to store a list of names or IDs in the table_type_name field, or just a single name/ID?

Comment: In general I want to store different layout types. To know which one to choose I use the dropdown list which is generated from the available entries. What I want to store is the id of the chosen entry. I will edit the question and try to make this more clear

Answer (score 1):

These changes made this problem work:

```
db.define_table('content',
    Field('content_type_id', db.content_type)
    )

db.define_table('layout_type',
    Field('layout_type_name', 'string'),
    format='%(layout_type_name)s'
    )
```

[This post about record representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744880/representation-format-in-web2py-database) is exactly what I was initially looking for.

Comment: Your code is confusing -- the `content_type_id` field references the `db.cms_content_type` table, yet its `IS_IN_DB` validator checks records in a different table (i.e., `db.layout_type`). Either there is an error in your code, or the code will not work as you expect.

Comment: Also, there is no need to specify the `IS_IN_DB` validator explicitly. Instead, you can set the "format" argument of the `db.layout_type` table to '%(layout_type_name)s`, and the validator will be created automatically.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the sharp eye - I completely messed the code up... I found an older post from you about the same problem.